# sort the frequency of a specific repetitive word in a file

Tags: regex, python-3.x

[image: screenshot of my file]

I've tried this code to sort the frequency of 'frankfurt' to show it.

but its not working here is the error :

```
for word in match_pattern:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

here is the code:

```py
import re
import string
frequency = {}
document_text = open('airlines.txt', 'r')
text_string = document_text.read().lower()
match_pattern = re.search(r'Frankfurt', text_string)
word = ("Frankfurt")
for word in match_pattern:
    count = frequency.get(word, 0)
    frequency[word] = count + 1
    print(frequency[word])
```

thanks for your help guys.

Comment: change `search` to `finditer`, and please for a record, don't post an image, post the text itself in order to make it easier for us to debug.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη if your comment solves the issue, please convert it into an answer so OP can approve and upvote.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη My comment has two reasons: the first was for you and the second is for future readers who could (potentially) have an approved answer which is easier to find than looking through comments...

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη of course if this is a duplicate, just flag it as such. 100%

Comment: all right guys I got this, thank u dudes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some errors. Your error is due to the fact that match_pattern is None. 
Also even if we assume it is not None, you could not iterate over match_pattern which is not utterable (read the re.search docstring). You did not close the file after opening it, etc.
I propose you to use Counter from collections library.

```
from collections import Counter

with open('airlines.txt','r') as f:
    document_text = f.read()

text_string = document_text.lower()

counts = Counter(text_string.split())
print(counts["frankfurt"])
```

Comment: thaaank youuuu @EPH , it worked good .

Comment: thank u guys soo muuch